# Currently executing queries - Teradata

Tags: teradata

I wanted to fetch the currently executing queries in Teradata and when I ran the below SQL and I got the error message as 'Failed 9881 : Function 'MonitorSQLText' called with an invalid number or type of parameters'. I am using TD 14.10

```
SELECT *  FROM TABLE (MonitorSQLText(-1, '*', 0)) AS T2;
```

Please help  me with this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MonitorSQLText` can only be applied to a single session.

To get info for all sessions you must use `MonitorSession(-1, '*', 0)`, when you do it in a Stored Procedure you can run it as a cursor and process each row.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and it can't be used dynamically either, so you need to get a session # first, and then apply it to the SQLText. I removed my answer.